# Automatic Weight fails totally

Tags: rigging, parent, rigify

I have this model here and it is symmetrical.

I removed doubles, I recalculated the normals, I fixed non-manifolds, I removed existing vertex groups. But still, when I try to parent my mesh to the rig it fails. What could be the issue here?

[My .blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zusvdmzrf154ine/Rig%20error.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Hello, please [edit] your question and add images. Your question should not rely on downloading a file. In the future, please use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload blend files. Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like parenting high-poly meshes fails, I don't know why, but if you merge by distance with a value of 0.0005 it won't be noticeable and it will parent correctly (and anyway you should work with a much less polygon version)

Comment: The issue is around/in eyes and mouth. Don't know why either. In these parts: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv7xT.png

Comment: Thank you moonboots, it is working well now!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like parenting high-poly meshes fails, I don't know why, but if you merge by distance with a value of 0.0005 it won't be noticeable and it will parent correctly (and anyway you should work with a much less polygon version)